# How to avoid Cassandra StorageService class InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, exception, cassandra, storage

I have create StorageService class object as follows

```
StorageService service=new StorageService();
```

When this instruction encountered following exception has been thrown.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageService
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.<init>(StorageService.java:233)
    at com.exterro.edrm.restore.EmbeddedService.main(EmbeddedService.java:144)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageService
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:453)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.internal_addObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1484)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:963)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:917)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:312)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:482)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.<init>(StorageService.java:229)
    ... 1 more
```

What should I add or change to avoid this exception?

After creating this StorageService class object I have to invoke `startRPCServer()` to start the cassandra service as well regeister MBean to use nodetool utility programmatically in java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do all of this just to use JMX?  If so, you're doing way more than you need to.  Here's an example of a JMX client in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/examples/Basic/Client.java

If you want to do some of the same things that nodetool does, I suggest just pulling the relevant parts of the code out and pasting them into your application.  There's no need to run nodetool itself within your application.